# Check if form fields have values on page load and if so, show labels?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, input, pageload

I have a form where small labels are displayed above each field, once the user adds a value to that field.

This for is sometimes loaded with some of the fields being pre-populated.

How would i check on page load if any of the form fields have a value and if so, have the label visible?

Here's my current code for displaying labels once a field has a value:

```
$('.form-control').blur(function() {
    if( $(this).val() ) {
        $(this).prev().show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on page load try this:

```
$('.form-control').each(function() {
 if( $(this).val() ) {
    $(this).prev().show();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-control').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != ''){
            $(this).prev().show();
        }
    });        
});
```

On document ready, for each .form-control, if the input's value is not blank, do whatever code you would to show the label.

Comment: Thanks for this, but Anuj's method appears to have done the trick! Not sure if this method is any better or just a different approach...

Answer (score 0):

Using `focusout` Event wouldn't be much of an overkill, would it?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
                    // ALTHOUGH BLUR IS OK, ONE COULD SIMPLY BIND THE .form-control CLASSES TO THE focusout EVENT
                    // THIS ENSURES THAT THERE IS A HIGHER LIKELIHOOD THAT THE FIELD IN QUESTION ONCE HAD FOCUS
                    // WHICH MAY IMPLY THAT THE USER ALSO INTERACTED WITH THE FIELD IN SOME WAY...
                $('.form-control').each(function(elem){
                    var objElem = $(this);
                    objElem.focusout(function(evt) {
                        if ($(this).val()) {
                            // NOW, YOU SHOULD KNOW WHICH METHOD TO USE TO TRAVERSE THE DOM
                            // AND GET AT THE LABEL....
                            // IN YOUR CASE IT SEEMS TO BE THE PREVIOUS ELEMENT BEFORE THE FORM-FIELD.
                            $(this).prev().show();
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
    })(jQuery);

    </script>
```